# Is LAN + Internet Meteor app possible?

Tags: node.js, meteor

Would it be possible to build a Meteor App, e.g. a chat app, that works both on the Internet and on LAN?

What I want here is that if the chat clients have the Internet connection, they will talk to each other updating/through the database hosted somewhere. If they have no Internet connection, they can still talk to each other through LAN, and once there's an Internet connection, the database will be updated from cache accordingly.

Comment: I could be wrong, but the only way I see that happening is if the server was located somewhere on a network that both the chat clients had access to with or without internet. On some internal network.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this using [WebRTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC). It's not really a meteor question, more of a general client-to-client communication question.

You can take a look at the source of my typhone project (https://github.com/chfritz/typhone), which uses WebRTC to share files between an android phone and a computer. It's written in meteor, too, so you might find code that you can reuse.

Comment: I like the typhone idea, but it complains of an unsatisfied dependency: chfritz:mobile-webrtc - can you publish that too please?

Comment: You can actually remove that. It's an empty package I was going to move all the webrtc code into, but haven't yet.

Comment: I've removed it in the source now, too. If you do another pull it should be gone.

Comment: Thanks for that, and sorry to be asking for more help, I just ran another build, and I'm getting this error: While building the application:
/Users/triton/senecto/kwiktry/typhone/app/client/style.scss:1:9: Scss compiler error: file to import not found or unreadable: .meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/meteoric_ionic-sass/ionic
Current dir: /Users/triton/senecto/kwiktry/typhone/app/client/

Do I need to load ionic somehow?

Comment: did you run just `meteor` first?

Comment: Yes, I ran meteor, what else should I do? Is there something from ionic that needs to be installed?

Comment: sorry, I don't recall how to get past that. I vaguely remember the error and having to manually copy some files from the .meteor/local folder, but the details escape me.